# How do I find a vector perpendicular to another vector in 2D and 3D?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

For example, given the 2D vector u=[2,3], how would I determine the vector that is perpendicular to u?

Also, given the 3D vector v=[3,6,1], how would I determine the vector that is perpendicular to u>

Comment: A vector that is perpendicular is one who when doing the dot product (inner product) with your vector results in zero.  You can describe this as a matrix equation, just like you can describe many other things in linear algebra as matrix equations, and the same techniques used to solve other matrix equations work here as well.

Comment: *the* vector perpendicular to $u$? A moments thought about the geometry here should convince you that there are infinitely many vectors perpendicular to $u$ in two dimensions, and a two-dimensional family of answers in three dimensions.

Comment: You will find that in $\Bbb R^n$, given a nonzero vector $v$ there is an entire $(n-1)$-dimensional subspace of $\Bbb R^n$ perpendicular to $v$.  There is more than just one vector perpendicular to it... so the phrasing "*how would I determine* **the** *vector...*" is improper as the usage of "the" would imply that you think there is only one.